# golang pprof heap count meaning

Tags: go, pprof

## Description

I try to use pprof to profile my programme, and i am using

```
import _ net/http/pprof to add /debug/pprof endpoints in my service.
```

access in browser:

```
http://ip:port/debug/pprof/
```

then i will have the following page:

[image: debug-pprof-heap]

### Everytime when i try to refresh this page, the number in the boxes keep increase!!

When i follow the link: http://ip:port/debug/pprof/heap?debug=1

i will see the following:

[image: debug-pprof-heap-detail]

the 4 numbers here :

```
2508: 273338776 [4733405: 12257136096]
```

means inuse_objects: inuse_space [all_objects: alloc_space], am i right?

## Question

### What do this two numbers in boxes actually mean?

Does the "heap count" has any relation with the `inuse_objects` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting [the template for the index page](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5bd88b0/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go#L325) shows that the count is produced by [pprof.Profile.Count](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/#Profile.Count):

> Count returns the number of execution stacks currently in the profile.

In other words, the index page shows the number of samples that have been collected for each type of profile so far. They are not related to any particular metric, such as inuse_objects or inuse_space.

Comment: Is the increasing of this two number, indicating memory leak?

Comment: @kvh, no, not at all. It means that more samples are added to a profile over time. Obviously the behavior of a program can change over time, so continuous profiling is totally expected.